# Dynamically delete rows using Javascript. Whats wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

The user inputs some text into a form and its stored in a variable 'userInput'
I have  html table with `id="myTable"`.
I want to iterate through the table using Javascript and delete all the rows where the value of the 3rd column in a row isn't equal to the userInput, but my code isn't working for some reason:

```
var theTable = document.getElementById("myTable");
for(int x = 0; x < theTable.rows.length; x++){
     if(theTable.rows[x].cells[2].innerHTML != userInput){
          theTable.deleteRow(x);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The first issue with this code that I see is that you are deleting rows in a forward moving loop, meaning if you delete row 3, row 4 will now be 3 etc (not an issue if only deleting a single row but not a good practice)..  You should delete in reverse ordered loop.

#### Also, you should probably compare the `innerText` vs `innerHTML`, I doubt the user input is HTML.

```
for(var x = theTable.rows.length; x > 0 ; x--){
  if(theTable.rows[x - 1].cells[2].innerText!= userInput){
      theTable.deleteRow(x -1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Also content of the cells might be formatted?
E.g. <b>asdf</b> != asdf

Answer (score 1):

1. In your for loop you need to change `int x` to `var x` to be valid in javascript.
2. To make sure, that every line is deleted, to only count up the iterator `x`, if a row **was not deleted**. (see the `else` statement)

```js
var userInput = 'keep me';

var theTable = document.getElementById("myTable");
for(var x = 0; x < theTable.rows.length;){
  if(theTable.rows[x].cells[2].innerHTML != userInput){
    theTable.deleteRow(x);
  } else {
    x += 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>keep me</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>delete me</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>delete me</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>delete me</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

try logging the outputs:

```
var theTable = document.getElementById("myTable");
for(int x = 0; x < theTable.rows.length; x++){
     console.log(theTable.rows[x].cells[2].innerHTML , userInput);
     if(theTable.rows[x].cells[2].innerHTML != userInput){
          theTable.deleteRow(x);
      }
}
```